# How can I safely connect a subpanel in a detached garage to the main with a 3-wire connection?

Tags: electrical, safety, grounding, subpanel

This weekend I attempted to install a breaker box into a pre-wired garage.  The previous owners took the breaker box with them when they moved, and since I have installed quite a few subpanels, it seemed like an easy job to replace it.

The subpanels I have installed have always used 4-wire connections, so I was surprised to find that only three wires had been run underground through the conduit, and the ground was attached to a separate rod at the garage.

Reading up on the permits for the house and some NEC info lead me to believe that this was a pre-2005 installation, at which point 3-wire was still allowed to connect a sub to a main in a detached structure.

My question is this:

What is the correct setup for neutral and ground in the sub panel?  Should they be bonded, and do I need to attach a ground to the buried rod at the garage as well?

Specifically, I need to know if this image shows a correct setup before I proceed.  This question has been touched upon in other posts, but not adequately answered:

[image: 3-wire feeder diagram]
<sub>(source: [nachi.org](https://www.nachi.org/forum/attachments/f19/75836d1404882959-square-d-sub-panel-3-wire-feeder-detached-building.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a situation where a 3 wire feeder can be used, you will need to bond the grounded (neutral) conductor to a proper grounding electrode system in the detached building. So yes, the diagram is correct.

***NOTE:*** The grounding electrode system, may be required to be made up of more than a single ground rod.

Comment: Thank you!

As I am unable to test the existing ground rod, I will be connecting a second one just to be safe.